# Why does offset for Khartoum is 0? Is there a bug in TimeZones?

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

Why does the following code:

```
System.out.println("Khartoum offset: " + TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Khartoum").getRawOffset());
// GMT+2

System.out.println("Moscow offset: " + TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow").getRawOffset());
// GMT+3

System.out.println("Cairo offset: " + TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Cairo").getRawOffset());
// GMT+2
```

produce this strange input:

```
Khartoum offset: 0, why is this 0??? It should have been 7200000
Moscow offset: 10800000 // 3 hours, which is OK for GMT+3
Cairo offset: 7200000 // 2 hours, which is OK for GMT+2
```

If you type `Khartoum time` in google you'll find out it's Khartoum has `GMT+2` (same as "Cairo").

**UPD**: `System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Khartoum").getRawOffset());` prints out `10800000` which is basically GMT+3. Shouldn't it print `7200000` (which corresponds to GMT+2), though (proof: what about this: [ideone.com/sm2SHC](https://ideone.com/sm2SHC))?

Comment: When I try it, `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Khartoum").getRawOffset()` returns `7200000`.

Comment: @khelwood what about this: https://ideone.com/sm2SHC?

Comment: The `TimeZone` class is long outdated, only one of the outdated date and time classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1. Today it is recommended that instead you use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its classes `ZoneId` and `ZoneRules`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Khartoum is located in Africa not in Asia, and the [TZDB also has this view](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/africa#L1162), so use:

```
Africa/Khartoum
```

Otherwise the old Timezone-API will fall back to GMT.

Comment: @AlexKornakov If you follow the tzdb-link given above then you will find that Khartoum changed its offset from UTC+3 to UTC+2 on 2017-11-01. Probably your Java is too old. You could update the underlying tzdb-version by downloading and executing the TZ-updater-tool from Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

See [`TimeZone.getAvailableIds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs()) for the list of supported timezone identifiers. `"Asia/Khartoum"` does not appear to be among them.

The javadoc for [`TimeZone.getTimeZone(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)) says

> Returns:
>      the specified TimeZone, or **the GMT zone if the given ID cannot be understood**.

*More*

On the other, if you check `"Africa/Khartoum"`

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Khartoum").getRawOffset()
```

it returns `7200000` (at least when I try it).

Answer (score 0):

If you're suspicious that there is another "Khartoum" e.g "Asia/Khartoum",
you can write the code to clear all your doubts:

```
String[] strings = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

for (String s : strings) {
    if (s.contains("Khartoum")) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The output is (even in Java 10)

> Africa/Khartoum

**EDIT**: Since you provided the code with wrong output, I'll post here the entire code I've written. Please, copy/paste this code, and show some feedback...

```
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Answer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] strings = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

        for (String s : strings) {
            if (s.contains("Khartoum")) {
                System.out.println("For " + s + " raw offset is "
                        + TimeZone.getTimeZone(s).getRawOffset());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Output should be:

> For Africa/Khartoum raw offset is 7200000

Comment: `System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Khartoum").getRawOffset());` outputs 7200000. Is that what you expected?

Comment: I checked your code, and the result isn't right... Why, I really don't know. Do you want me to post here my class?